# The function $\Psi:G \to G$ with $g \mapsto g^m$ is an automorphism.

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be an Abelian group of order $n$ and for a positive integer $m$ we have that $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

Then the function $\Psi:G \to G$ with $g  \mapsto g^m$ is an automorphism.

---

My try:

First I show that the function is homomorphism:
Let $g_1,g_2 \in G$ and consider $\Psi(g_1g_2)=(g_1g_2)^m$ and this is true since $G$ is a group,besides it's Abelian and so $\Psi(g_1g_2)=g_1^{m}g_2^{m}=\Psi(g_1)\Psi(g_1)$.

The function is clearly surjective.

To show that it's injective we need to show $\text{ker}(\Psi)=\left\{e_G\right\}$, if we assume there exists $e_G\ne g  \in\text{ker}(\Psi)$ then $\Psi(g)=e_G=g^m$,but I don't know how to continue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is the function clearly surjective ?

Comment: The word "consider" is not a magic spell that gets us out of showing $\Psi$ is surjective... Indeed if $m,n$ are not relatively prime then $\Psi$ is *not* surjective, yet you haven't used coprimality.

Comment: @45465, the point he is trying to make is that, you aren't considering some $g^m$ and finding that $g$ maps to it. You have to consider some $g \in G$. It is not obvious what element maps to $x^m = g$

Answer (score 2):

Any $f\colon X\to X$ is bijective if it is surjective/injective when $X$ is finite. In this case, you can also use the following. Since $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ there are integers $r, s$ such that $rm+sn = 1$, so if $g^m = 1$, then $g^{rm+sn} = g^{sn} = 1$ because $|G| = n$, but at the same time $g^{rm+sn} = g^1 = g$, hence $\Psi$ is injective.

To obtain surjectivity, observe that by $rm+sn=1$, we have for any $g\in G, (g^r)^m=g$.

Comment: @45465 No, it is surjective if for every $g\in G$, there is an $x\in G$ such that $\Psi(x) = g$, i.e., $\Psi$ takes every value in $G$.

Comment: @45465 what? I have proved that for any $g\in G, \Psi(g^r) = g$, hence $\Psi$ is surjective. When $m$ is not coprime to $n$, consider squaring in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{\pm 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

A (purely) group-theoretical argument here:

Suppose $g^m=e_G$, then $\text{ord}(g)|m$. By Lagrange's theorem we have $\text{ord}(g)|n$. Therefore $\text{ord}(g)$ is a common divisor of two relatively prime numbers, so $\text{ord(g)}=1$ and $g=e_G$.

Answer (score 0):

To show injectivity, suppose that $g^m = g_{1}^{m}$.

Then $g^mg_{1}^{-m} = 1 \implies g^mg_{-1}^m = 1 \implies (gg_{1}^{-1})^{m}=1$. Since $(m,n)=1, mx+ny=1$ and so $1=(gg_{1}^{-1})^{m} = (gg_{1}^{-1})^{1-ny} = gg_{1}^{-1} \implies g = g_{1}$ because $|G| = n$.